# formatting a number as text

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I would like to display the number 1 as low, 2 as medium, and 3 as high, but retain the underlying numerical values.  I know how to do this with 0's using custom formats, but can it be done with other numbers? Conditional formatting only the colors cells, is that correct? So, I don't think that will work.   Thanks.

Comment: you will need three coditional formatting rules that change the number format to use the desired text in place of positive numbers.

Comment: My question would be: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @FlexYourData [X Y problem?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 1):

If the cell will contain **ONLY** `1, 2 or 3`, then you can use this custom number format:

```
[=1]"low";[=2]"medium";"high"
```

How to ensure that depend on how the value gets into the cell.  If it is manually entered, you could use Data Validation.  If it is the result of the formula, then you can structure the formula to only output one of those values